# How to tell if a set is open in the Krull topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I'm an undergraduate not very familiar with topology trying to understand the so called Krull Topology in the context of infinite Galois Theory. We proceed as follows:

Let $\Omega/k$ be a (possibly infinite) Galois extension with group $G=G(\Omega/k)$.

For each $\sigma\in G$, we take the cosets $\sigma G(\Omega/M)$, with $M/k$ ranging the finite subextensions of $\Omega/k$ as a basis of neighbourhoods (or fundamental system of neighbourhoods) of $\sigma$.

How **exactly** does this define a topology?

I mean, given a subset $U\subseteq G$, which criterion do I have to check for this subset to be open?

I've seen a couple of other related questions, but none answered me in a satisfactory way. Many of these were particular analysis examples and I couldn't keep track of notation, for example.

I've heard that if we take a union of the fundamental systems of neighbourhoods of every point, we get a basis, but I don't know if this is correct.

Can someone please elaborate a little bit on the topic?

I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: As any other topology, a set is open if and only if it is a neighbourhood of all its points. So, given $U$, you have to check that for all $a \in U$, $a^{-1}U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ (which is equivalent to containing an open subgroup of $G$).

Comment: Thanks! So, for a subset $U$ to be open, I need to check that it is a neighbourhood of all of its points. Given a point $a\in U$, to check if $U$ is a neighbourhood of $a$, does it suffice to find a $G(\Omega/M)$, for some finite subextension $M/k$, such that $a G(\Omega /M)\subseteq U$?

Comment: Yes: this is exactly what you are supposed to do.